# Produce a list of appointments for each doctor; including doctors name, patient name, date, time and duration

Tags: mysql, database

I have three tables;

- Doctor
- Person
- Appointment

The table structure is:

doctor table:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
| doctor_id | phone_no | room_no | date_qualified | date_appointed |
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
| 50        | 1234     | 1       | 1963-09-01     | 1991-05-10     |
| 51        | 1235     | 2       | 1973-09-12     | 1991-05-10     |
| 52        | 1236     | 3       | 1990-10-02     | 1993-04-01     |
| 53        | 1237     | 4       | 1965-06-30     | 1994-03-01     |
+-----------+----------+---------+----------------+----------------+
```

person table

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
| person_id | initials | last_name | date_of_birth | sex  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
| 100       | T        | Williams  | 1972-01-12    | m    |
| 101       | J        | Garcia    | 1981-03-18    | f    |
| 102       | W        | Fisher    | 1950-10-22    | m    |
| 103       | K        | Waldon    | 1942-06-01    | m    |
| 104       | P        | Timms     | 1928-06-03    | m    |
| 105       | A        | Dryden    | 1944-06-23    | m    |
| 106       | F        | Fogg      | 1955-10-16    | f    |
| 150       | T        | Saj       | 1994-06-17    | m    |
| 50        | A        | Cameron   | 1937-04-04    | m    |
| 51        | B        | Finlay    | 1948-12-01    | m    |
| 52        | C        | King      | 1965-06-06    | f    |
| 53        | D        | Waldon    | 1938-07-08    | f    |
+-----------+----------+-----------+---------------+------+
```

appointment table

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| doctor_id | patient_id | appt_date  | appt_time | appt_duration |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 50        | 100        | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 100        | 1994-08-16 | 10:50:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 102        | 1994-08-21 | 11:20:00  |            20 |
| 50        | 103        | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  |            10 |
| 50        | 104        | 1994-08-10 | 10:20:00  |            20 |
| 52        | 102        | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  |            10 |
| 52        | 105        | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  |            10 |
| 52        | 150        | 2014-03-10 | 12:00:00  |            15 |
| 53        | 106        | 1994-08-10 | 11:30:00  |            10 |
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

I need to create a query to Produce a list of appointments for each doctor including the doctor's name, the patient's name and the date time and duration of the appointment. The result should be ordered by doctor's name and date/time of appointment.

I tried the following code:

```
select person.last_name, person.initials, person.last_name, appointment.appt_date, appointment.appt_time, appointment.appt_duration -> from doctor inner join appointment on doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id -> inner join person on person.person_id = appointment.patient_id -> order by person.initials, person.last_name, appointment.appt_date, appointment.appt_time;
```

And I got the following result which doesnt have the doctors name and also theres 2 columns for the last name when there should only be one.

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+ 
| last_name | initials | last_name | appt_date  | appt_time | appt_duration | 
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+ 
| Dryden    | A        | Dryden    | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  | 10            | 
| Fogg      | F        | Fogg      | 1994-08-10 | 11:30:00  | 10            | 
| Waldon    | K        | Waldon    | 1994-08-10 | 10:10:00  | 10            | 
| Timms     | P        | Timms     | 1994-08-10 | 10:20:00  | 20            | 
| Saj       | T        | Saj       | 2014-03-10 | 12:00:00  | 15            | 
| Williams  | T        | Williams  | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  | 10            | 
| Williams  | T        | Williams  | 1994-08-16 | 10:50:00  | 10            | 
| Fisher    | W        | Fisher    | 1994-08-10 | 10:00:00  | 10            | 
| Fisher    | W        | Fisher    | 1994-08-21 | 11:20:00  | 20            | 
+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: welcome user3472448. Please pay attention with your question's presentation style so the people can understand what you ask easier and may help you. While in asking mode, you can utilize the help parts. (quick or detailed). Welcome again.

Comment: This query is fine. Your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: :-) as you see, I couldn't also achieved it. Best is better than 'better'. Thanks to cpburnz

Comment: @Strawberry Dear friend, the question's original displaying style was really difficult to read. I tried to edit. I meade it better. And as you see cpburnz made it much better. So please let's not be rude to each other. as you see, owner of question is new to SO, I am also not a expert but I tried my best just like user3472448

Comment: @AndreChenier You're clearly very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Last name comming 2 times because you are selecting it 2 times

```
select person.last_name, <------ here
person.initials, person.last_name, <---- here
appointment.appt_date, 
appointment.appt_time, 
appointment.appt_duration 
from doctor  
inner join appointment on  doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id 
inner join person on  person.person_id = appointment.patient_id
order by 
person.initials,
person.last_name, 
appointment.appt_date, 
appointment.appt_time;
```

Remove one of them

Doctor name is not showing since you are not selecting it. And your table for doctor does not have a name as u shown. Check in your DB if it has a name and just add that in the query.

With your requirement check if the following helps !!

```
select person.last_name, 
person.initials, 
d.last_name as DoctorName, 
appointment.appt_date, 
appointment.appt_time, 
appointment.appt_duration 
from appointment  
inner join doctor on  doctor.doctor_id = appointment.doctor_id 
left join person on  person.person_id = appointment.patient_id
left join 
( 
  select * from person 
)d
on  d.person_id = appointment.doctor_id 
order by 
person.initials,
person.last_name, 
appointment.appt_date, 
appointment.appt_time;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df2e0a/14

Comment: No the doctor table is not meant to have the doctors name, the doctors  names are in the persons table with the patients names.

Comment: Well with the current scenario the doc names could be retrieved but i will need to post these tables with data on sqlfiddle.com we can make a query and for that.

Comment: I meant u add the tables and data in sqlfiddle.com so that we can tale a look !!

Comment: Ive added the tables and the data to sqlfiddle.com, what shall i do now